# How to perform a segue from a view container to another external view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a view container that contains different view controllers in it when the user presses a button the view changes just inside the container, the parent view stays unchanged. I need to perform a segue from one of the views managed by the container to another external view, so I need the parent view to change. If I use a normal segue from the storyboard the view it's going to be displayed in the container, how do I change that so the parent view can change?

Comment: is that a container a container view and you are embedding that container into a super view controller ?

Comment: Yes, I have a super view with a container that manages some subviews and I need a segue from one of the subviews to an external view at the same level of the parent

Comment: One way is you can send a delegation to the parent view to perform the segue. And for the other way i can help you out only when i can see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the parent view is an `UIViewController` then you can open the view by doing:

```
self.present(viewController: externalView)
```

from the parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can referenciate hte father view controller to make the seguelike this.

```
self.parent?.performSegue(withIdentifier:"idetnitifier" , sender: selectedUser)
```

change your segue identifier to match yours and sender could be nil or any?